# $ajax request giving me a net::ERR_ABORTED 404

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to use giftup.app api and for some reason i can't get access to it.
To get the full documentation please see: https://giftup.app/docs/api#!/Gift_cards/ApiGift_cardsByCodeRe_activatePost

The API Key was recently generated for testing purposes only.

At first, i had the CORS Policy blocking me and so i added: dataType: 'jsonp', to my $ajax call but after that i'm getting the following message:
net::ERR_ABORTED 404

Is there anything i'm missing on the code?

```js
$.ajax({
  url: "https://api.giftup.app/",
  async: false,
  headers: {
    'Authorization': '(redacted)',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    'x-giftup-testmode': true 
  },
  crossDomain: true,
  dataType: 'jsonp', //this solved my CORS policy issue
  contentType: 'application/json',
}).done((data) => {
  console.log(data);
})
```

I get exactly this message:

> jquery.min.js:2 GET https://api.giftup.app/ callback=jQuery33101561895133289939_1548967521051&_=1548967521052 
>       net::ERR_ABORTED 404

Comment: Ick... `async: false,`

Comment: Do **not** use `async: false`.

Comment: You can't just magically add JSONP unless the API resource supports that format

Comment: @TylerRoper why should i avoid `async: false` ?

Comment: You can not add cors to the JavaScript code either.... The server has to grant you access.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

So I had to contact the company because of the issue.
I was told that they has a server issue and no need to use `dataType: 'jsonp'`

Thanks for the help though.

Answer (score 0):

If this is your actual request you'r forgetting to call an endpoint like `gift-cards`